# how to fixed Module not found : syntax error

Tags: smartcontracts, truffle, decentralized-applications

I follow the [Getting Started](https://enigma.co/protocol/GettingStarted.html), [Writing a Secret Contract](https://enigma.co/protocol/SecretContracts.html), [Creating a React Front-End](https://enigma.co/protocol/CreateReactFrontend.html), but I get this

> Syntax Error about enigma_dapp/client/src/App.js

I copy the Creating a React Front-End said App.js, Error follow the pictures

Picture as following the "Module", "Failed"

[Module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPFYO.png)

[Failed to compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8eiq.png)

If I didn’t add [Writing a Secret Contract](https://enigma.co/protocol/SecretContracts.html), [Creating a React Front-End](https://enigma.co/protocol/CreateReactFrontend.html) part

I get “Enigma setup still loading”

Picture as follow the "Original view"

[Original view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxRas.png)

I'm sure the */enigma_dapp/*   have package.json
and */enigma_dapp/client/* have package.json, package-lock.json, yarn.lock

but */enigma_dapp/client/src/* don't have any of them, how can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I receive the solution about this enigma version.

It's a early version , so it's not available now. (or bugs a lot)

https://forum.enigma.co/t/app-js-and-syntax-error/1090